# Create "valid" timer not tied with frame rate?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, timer

I understand it is not recommended for a timer's delay to be under 20, but I have two Timers: one with a one millisecond delay, the second with 5000 (though it doesn't matter).

I use the `TIMER_TICK` event for the first timer so I can subtract its `currentCount` from the second timer's `delay` (5000).  However, because timers in as3 are tied with the **`frameRate`**, and less than 20 millisecond delays are not recommended, the timer ticks a lot slower.

**The question:**

Is there a way to somehow **"untie"** its relationship with the **`frameRate`**?

I've done **research to help with answering this question**, and **`getTimer()`** seems to give a valid integer when I `trace` it.  So there may be something I could do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sad thing is that developers don't really get to "untie" the Timer or similar classes from the frame rate.

It's totally useless to have a Timer with a `delay=1` as it will simply not fire that often. So refreshing something with an interval smaller than frame rate is not going to give you guaranteed results.

You can however see how much time has passed since the last update. Let's say you have an emulation where a Sprite moves with a speed 1px/ms. Trying to move the Sprite that fast will fail. Even if it's calculated fast enough the monitor won't refresh the screen so easy.

But you can know how much time passed for the code to execute in milliseconds to move the Sprite that many pixels on next update:

```
var startTime:int = getTimer();

// YOUR CODE HERE

var timePassed:int = getTimer() - startTime; // returns the amount of time spent on code execution
```

Keep in mind that getTimer() starts counting since the virtual machine started. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer()

Here is a blog post written by one of the Adobe Flash Player engineers explaining why it's impossible to target small time intervals and a little of the FP model in general: http://www.kaourantin.net/2006/05/frame-rates-in-flash-player.html

Comment: great, simple solution.  I do think Adobe should change their methods on frameRate...

Comment: I just realized something really great that's making me feel stupid: `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You will not get timer events faster than once per frame, period. You indeed can count elapsed time via `getTimer()`, using capture then compare technique via enter frame listener, like this:

```
var oldTime:int;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    var frameTime:int=getTimer()-oldTime;
    oldTime=getTimer();
    // process frameTime
}
```

Be warned however, this is one behavior that's being hated in games, that is, if Flash player would lag for some reason, the `getTimer()` difference per frame will spike, making your game engine to behave like a lot of time passed without any actions from the player, and in such games the player is expected to react in realtime, thus the game engine will likely react with a game over situation within a single frame. The workaround is to cap frame time difference with a reasonable value that's corresponding to a decent framerate below which you don't expect your game to be run in any circumstances (say, 10fps, 1000/10 = 100).

```
static const FRAME_CAP:int=100;
if (frameTime>FRAME_CAP) frameTime=FRAME_CAP;
```

PS: I expect the actual reason of timers being tied to frame rate is that the timer check routine is now being called internally alongside creating the enter frame or exit frame events that are then propagated through the entire display list, and the actual update time for timers is then calculated exactly via `getTimer()`, which are then compared with timers' internal "next fire at" field, to fire corresponding `TIMER_TICK` events and to update these with `getTimer()+delay`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I found was using a tween engine and listening to the change events:

http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

Comment: great solution, but maybe provide a little more detail on the exact Event 'change event' to help other users?  It's great you talked about the link, but it seems a little broad.  I wish I could accept your answer, but I found a better one.